# Does there always exist a continuous map saturating a given open set?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two general topological spaces. Is the following statement true?

For any open $U\subset X$, there exists an open $V\subset Y$ and a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$, such that $f^{-1}V=U$.

Comment: Take $Y$ to be finite, and $X$ to have an infinite number of open sets.

Comment: But there are potentially many $f$'s?

Comment: You are correct, sloppy thinking on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ only has one element then $f^{-1}(V)\in\{\varnothing,X\}$ for any open set $V$.

So if $X$ has a non-trivial open set then it does not work.

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}(V)=\{\emptyset,X\}$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft (typo, repaired) Because $V=\varnothing$ or $V=Y=\{y\}$ and $f:X\to Y$ can only be the constant function.

Comment: Right. I did not consider this degenerate situation. Can one say anything about the case where $Y$ has more than one element?

Comment: Here is another degenerate situation: let $Y$ have indiscrete topology. Then again $f^{-1}(V)\in\{\varnothing,X\}$ for every open $V$, and $Y$ can have as much elements as you want.

Comment: Right, it seems the question is only interesting if more regularity is assumed on the topology of Y.